# How to test whether $qn^r$ is a product of $r+1$ integers such that each integer is between $n$ and $q$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Suppose we have positive integers $q$, $n$, and $r$ with $n\lt q$.

What is the easiest way to test whether or not $qn^r$ is a product of $r+1$ positive integers such that each integer is between $n$ and $q$?

A way that would be easy to implement in a computer program would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_1, \ldots, p_m$ be the distinct primes dividing $q n$, with $q = p_1^{a_1} \ldots p_m^{a_m}$ and $n = p_1^{b_1} \ldots p_m^{b_m}$.  Then
your $r+1$ positive integers will be 
$ p_1^{x_{1j}} \ldots p_m^{x_{mj}}$ for $j=1\ldots r+1$ where $x_{ij}$ are nonnegative integers satisfying the constraints

$$ \eqalign{ \sum_{j=1}^{r+1} x_{ij} &= r a_i + b_i,\ i=1\ldots m \cr
     \log(n) &< \sum_{i=1}^{m} x_{ij} \log(p_i) < \log(q) , \ j=1\ldots r+1 \cr}
$$

You might try integer linear programming or an SMT solver, if the numbers involved are too big to make brute-force search feasible.

Comment: What about if $\log(n)+1\gt\log(q)-1$?

Comment: Oops, edited it...